# Using the Alembic bulk_insert function only when the table is empty

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

At the moment I'm using Alembic to create a SQLite database. Now I have a table that needs default data when creating the table.

#### The issue

I found the `bulk_insert` function that allows you to insert data on upgrades and downgrades. The problem I am now encountering is that on each upgrade, the 'data seed' is re-added to the table.

#### How I solved it (for now)

By dropping and re-adding the table I fix the issue with this. (see code below)

```py
def upgrade():
    ${upgrades if upgrades else "pass"}

    meta = MetaData(bind=op.get_bind())
    meta.reflect(only=('day'))

    # DROP TABLE AND ADD IT AGAIN 
    day_table = Table('day', meta)
    op.drop_table(day_table)
    day_table = op.create_table('day',
                    sa.Column('id', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
                    sa.Column('week_day', sa.Integer(), nullable=True),
                    sa.Column('label', sa.String(length=100), nullable=True),
                    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id'))
    op.create_index(op.f('ix_day_id'), 'day', ['id'], unique=False)

    # DAY TABLE SEED 
    op.bulk_insert(day_table, [
        {'week_day': None,'label': 'day'},
        {'week_day': None,'label': 'workday'},
        {'week_day': 0,'label': 'monday'},
        {'week_day': 1,'label': 'tuesday'},
        {'week_day': 2,'label': 'wednesday'},
        {'week_day': 3,'label': 'thursday'},
        {'week_day': 4,'label': 'friday'},
        {'week_day': 5,'label': 'saturday'},
        {'week_day': 6,'label': 'sunday'},
    ])
```

#### The problem with my fix

Within my code I create the table `day` from a separate python file called `day_table.py`. So basically when I'm going for this approach and I wan't to change something within the day_table I have to change it in `day_table.py` and in `script.py.mako`.

#### What I need

I'm wondering if someone has a solution that makes it possible to only add the seed data when the `day_table` is empty. I looked in Alembic's documentation but could not find this.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try to write a raw sql to identify if the table is empty.

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import text
conn = op.get_bind()
res = conn.execute(text("select id from day"))
if not len(res.fetchall()):
    op.bulk_insert(day_table, [
        {'week_day': None,'label': 'day'},
        {'week_day': None,'label': 'workday'},
        {'week_day': 0,'label': 'monday'},
        {'week_day': 1,'label': 'tuesday'},
        {'week_day': 2,'label': 'wednesday'},
        {'week_day': 3,'label': 'thursday'},
        {'week_day': 4,'label': 'friday'},
        {'week_day': 5,'label': 'saturday'},
        {'week_day': 6,'label': 'sunday'},
    ])
```